# Why am I getting this error message? C++

Tags: c++

I am getting this error every time I try to run my program.

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of
>
> 'std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Bin
{  
  string desc;
  int partsQty;
};

void addParts(Bin bList[], int i);
void removeParts(Bin bList[], int i);
int main() {
    char response;
    int binNumber;
    const int NUM_OF_BINS = 11;
    Bin binList[NUM_OF_BINS] = {
    {0,0},
    {"Valve", 10},
    {"Earing",5},
    {"Bushing",15},
    {"Coupling",21},
    {"Flange",7},
    {"Gear",5},
    {"Gear Housing",5},
    {"Vaccum Gripper",25},
    {"Cable",18},
    {"Rod",12}
   };
for(int i=1;i < 11;i++)
{
    cout << "Bin #" << i << " Part: " << binList[i].desc << " Quantity " << binList[i].partsQty << endl;
}
   cout << "Please select a bin or enter 0 to terminate";
   cin >> binNumber;
   cout << "Would you like to add or remove parts from a certain bin?(A or R)";
   cin >> response;
   if(response == 'a')
       addParts(binList, binNumber);
   else if(response == 'r')
       removeParts(binList, binNumber);
   return 0;

}

void addParts(Bin bList[], int i)
{
   int parts;
   int num;
   cout << "How many parts would you like to add?";
   cin >> num;
   parts = bList[i].partsQty + num;
   cout << "Bin # " << i << " now contains " << parts << " parts";

}

void removeParts(Bin bList[], int i)
{
   int parts;
   int number;
   cout << "Which bin would you like to remove parts to?";
   cin >> i;
   cout << "How many parts would you like to remove?" << endl;
   cin >> number;
   parts = bList[i].partsQty - number;
   if(parts < 0)
      cout << "Please enter a number that isn't going to make the amount of parts in the bin negative.";
    cin >> number;
    parts = bList[i].partsQty - number;
    cout << "The remaining amount of parts in bin #" << i << " is " << parts;

}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: You're initializing a string with a null pointer.  A debugger will show you where and you can probably work out why from there.

Comment: Please revise your title so it will be useful to others. As written, it is uselessly vague. Pretty much every question on this site could be of the form "Why am I getting this error message?"

Answer (score 2):

It comes from:

```
{0,0}
```

in your list of initializers for `binList`.  `0` is not a correct initializer for `std::string`.  You could perhaps use `{"", 0}` instead, or even `{}`.

Another idea might be to revise your program logic so that you do not require a dummy entry at the start of the array.